# Is a bounde entire function of exponential type constant on a any compact?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, entire-functions, liouville-function

Let $\phi$ be an entire function of exponential type. That is:

$$\exists M, c>0,\quad \forall z\in \mathbb{C}\quad |\phi(z)|\leq M e^{c|z|}. $$

On any compact set $|z|=R$, we have:

$$|\phi(z)|\leq M e^{cR} $$
Hence, $\phi$ is a bounded entire function on any compact set. My question is the following:

Can we apply the theorem of Liouville to say that $\phi$ is contant on any compact? or the Liouville Theorem is only applied on the whole complex plane and so we cannot deduce anything from the previous statement?

Many thank's.

Comment: $e^z$ is a simple function of exponential type. Is it “constant on any compact set”? – Also “constant on any compact set” would imply that the function is constant everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liouville's Theorem is applicable only to bounded  analytic functions on the entire complex plane. **Every entire function is bounded on compact sets**. For example $f(z)=z$ is also bounded on compact sets but  it is not constant on compact sets.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you please tell me in which cases can we conclude that an entire function is constant everywhere? There is the Liouville's theorem and what else?

Comment: @Student A powerful generalization of Liouville's theorem is little Picard's theorem which states the image of an entire non constant function must avoid at most one value.

Comment: @Student A slight generaliztion is $|f(z) \leq C |z|^{t}$ with $0<t<1$ implies that $f$ is a constant.

Comment: @Caffeine You should also note that a bounded polynomial on $\mathbb C$ is a constant. This is elementary and does not require Liouville's Theorem. Boundedness on the whole of  $\mathbb C$ is crucial (but boundeness outside  a discrete set of points is also enough).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy isn't boundedness in an unbounded set also enough?

Comment: @Caffeine No. $\sin z$ and $\cos z$ are bounded on the real line !

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy obviously. I was talking about polynomials